# Bootstrap two-row grid issue (the top row is smaller than second)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am learning Bootstrap and am struggling with something that may be simple but I just cannot figure...

I am doing some experiments and there is this very primitive design compounded by a row with only one col (a title) and below this another row with two content cols. I cannot think on something more simple than this!

The problem is that no matter what I do the top row (title) insists on be smaller than the contents row. Also there is a blank space between the first and the second row.

My code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        user-scalable-no,
        initial-scale=1.0,
        maximum-scale=1.0,
        minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tabelas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        header {
            background:#2c3e50;
            color:#fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <header>
                   <h1 class="text-center">
                        My Title
                    </h1>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9" style="background:#e7e1c7;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took.
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:#a0c9f1;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took.
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set background to the header element, *not* the div which has the `col-sm` class... while for the columns below, you have added a background to the div with the `col-sm-9` and `col-sm-3` classes

just add a class with your background to the div with the bootstrap class, this way the padding will be included in the background - like below:

```css
.header-parent-div {
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm header-parent-div">
      <header>
        <h1 class="text-center">
          My Title
        </h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background:#e7e1c7;">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:#a0c9f1;">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly... I am bewitched by Bootstrap! Thank you very much! :^)

Answer (score 0):

How about this way? Fell free to set the col width as needed (col-sm-9 etc.)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
       Header

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
            cell 1
         </div>

         <div class="col">
           cell 2
         </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```